# AS3: zoom and pan movieclip in adobe air android

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am using gestouch library on github.https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch

zoomall is my movieclip, I am able to zoom in and out at a specific point.
here is my code,

```
import org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent;
import org.gestouch.gestures.ZoomGesture;

var zoom: ZoomGesture*;

zoom = new ZoomGesture(zoomall);
zoom.addEventListener(org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent.GESTURE_BEGAN, onGesture);
zoom.addEventListener(org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent.GESTURE_CHANGED, onGesture);

function onGesture(event: org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent): void {

    const gesture: ZoomGesture = event.target as ZoomGesture;

    var matrix: Matrix = zoomall.transform.matrix;
    var transformPoint: Point = matrix.transformPoint(zoomall.globalToLocal(zoom.location));
    matrix.translate(-transformPoint.x, -transformPoint.y);
    matrix.scale(gesture.scaleX, gesture.scaleY);
    matrix.translate(transformPoint.x, transformPoint.y);
    zoomall.transform.matrix = matrix;
}
```

Here I want to restrict the zoom in and out to specific scale.
And I also want to pan the movieclip(zoomall) and it should not pan outside the device screen.

Comment: We can see that you're updating transformation matrix to scale and move object. What is the problem to limit that transformation?

Comment: @Pavelfljōt How to give minimum and maximum zooming limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You realize that by calling matrix.scale(B, B) you simply do A * B = C,
where **A** is current scale and **C** is resulting scale?
So if you don't want **C** to be bigger than maximum **maxC**, you should limit **B**:

```
B = Math.min(B, maxC / A)
```

Same for minimum **minC**:

```
B = Math.max(minC / A, B)
```

So you will have:

```
// assuming you keep the scale ratio
var minS:Number = MIN_SCALE / zoomall.scaleX;
var maxS:Number = MAX_SCALE / zoomall.scaleX;
var s:Number = Math.max(minS, Math.min(gesture.scaleX, maxS));
matrix.scale(s, s);
```

Comment: But my panning problem remain as it is. I know this library is written by you, and you can solve my problem. Plz tell me how to pan the movieclip 'within the boundary'(screen area). And panning should be done with single finger only.

Comment: I'm sure you can manage to do the boundaries using similar approach. Ask if something _specific_ will trouble you.

Comment: I spend lots of my time on this. Can u plz tell me the solution how to do that, if you have.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try what flash is all ready built with these are great and simple tutorials that may help you out.

Pan tutorial
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3pangesture/
Pinch/Zoom
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3pinchzoom/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanx for your help. But I suggest you to use the gestouch library, it is far better than this.